# Gnuplot: splot grid filled with an exactly one color

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I have been thinking about drawing some 3d plots in `gnuplot` by an explicit formula with parametric option avaliable.
I want to fill the grid gaps with an exactly one color.
I know that I can for example fill the grid using `with pm3d` option, but then the color is related to function `z` argument.
Here is an example:

```
set parametric
set hidden3d
sp u,u,u*v w pm3d,\
   v,u*v,v w pm3d
```

[image: Example plot]

How to set color (inside splot grid) for the first curve to  blue, and the other one to red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple answer that does exactly what you ask, but it is only available in the development version of gnuplot.  Previous versions had a bug that made assignment of explicit colors incompatible with hidden surface handling in pm3d. If you are able to build gnuplot from the development git repository, it would accept this command sequence:

```
set parametric
set pm3d depthorder
sp u,u,u*v w pm3d fillcolor "blue", \
   v,u*v,v w pm3d fillcolor "red"
```

Note that "set hidden3d" does not work for pm3d surfaces.  If you cannot build from source then your best bet is to switch to a non-parametric equivalent and a custom palette for which you know some palette value that is blue and another that is red. In that case the command sequence would be something like

```
unset parametric
set palette defined (0.0 "red", 1.0 "blue")
set pm3d depthorder noborder
splot '++' using 1:1:($1*$2):(1.0) with pm3d, \
      '++' using 2:($1*$2):2:(0.0) with pm3d
```

The intersection of surfaces in pm3d is not smooth because every facet is either drawn or not drawn, there is no subdivision of facets that happen to intersect. You can minimize this by using a finer grid:

```
set samples 200
set isosamples 200
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Gnuplot  surprises me at each time :)